# How to clear history or remove pages or components in history in Ionic 4 or Angular 7

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I am creating a logout page in Ionic 4, what i want is to clear the router history so the back button dont work, plus i want to know how can i destroy logout page once i am navigated to Login Screen or before navigating to the Login Page.

I tried running the code in the Construction function to clear the local storage and all that works fine for the first time but second time its not running that code. According to my understand the page is already loaded so its not running the Constructor function again. I tried putting my the code in the on ngDoCheck() but its triggered multiple times which i dont want.

I want to clear the history of routing so the back button dont works once i logout, plus i want to know how can i clear or remove the pages which i visited perviously.

Comment: If you are using Ionic 4 & Angular then you can take advantage of Router Outlet functionality provided by Ionic
https://beta.ionicframework.com/docs/api/router-outlet

Answer (score 2):

You cannot prevent the user from clicking back or delete his history but you can add a guard to your login page so that it will redirect the user once he's logged in. It should go something like

#### The guard file

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
  canActivate(
    next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
    if(isUserLoggedIn()){ // this redirects the user
       this.router.navigate(['/logged-in-users-area']);
    }
    return isUserLoggedIn(); // this prevents him from reaching the login page
  }
}
```

#### You routes file

```
const routes: Routes = [{
    path: 'login',
    component: MyLoginComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
  }]
```

Comment: Thanks for the help Adam. Do you know, how can you refresh the content if the user visiting the same page again. I have checked RouterReuseStrategy but i am not sure how to set it up.

Answer (score -3):

use window.location.reload while logout

```
window.location.reload();
```

Comment: We cannot reload mobile applications, on web it's fine.